# How to handle scoped storage backward compatibility?

Tags: android, scoped-storage

My app's **targetSdkVersion** is 30, now I am trying to save image in the gallery. it works in android 11 and android 10 but does not work in android 9 and below versions.

*Shows error (permission denial) in android 9 and below versions.*

**CODE**

```
 public fun saveImageToStorage(
        mContext: DisplayActivity,
        bitmap: Bitmap,
        filename: String = "screenshot.jpg",
        )
{
    try {
         val values = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename)
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, directory)
                    }
         mContext.contentResolver.run {
                   val uri =
                   mContext.contentResolver.insert(mediaContentUri, values)
                            ?: return
                   imageOutStream = openOutputStream(uri) ?: return
                }  
       imageOutStream.use { bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it) }
        } catch (th: Throwable) {
           
        }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

No permission declared in manifest file

Comment: For those versions you should continue to do it as you used to do.

Comment: But play console policy will allow WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes certainly it will.

Answer (score 1):

keep using the "old ways" of external storage, by asking permission of external storage for android 9 and below

just add this in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`MediaStoreCompat` from [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage) can handle the backward compatibility:

```kotlin
val fileDesc = FileDescription(fileName, "", "image/jpg")
val mediaFile = MediaStoreCompat.createImage(applicationContext, fileDesc, ImageMediaDirectory.PICTURES)
mediaFile?.openOutputStream()?.use { bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, it) }
```